# What is the best way to create a local development environment in a linux machine without being in sudoers

Tags: linux, python, sudo

I use a workstation for my development but it does not include all the libraries for my case. I like to install them for my use without any system wide effect. How should I proceed this is a linux machine?

Specifically, I need the Python scientific stack and Caffe deep-learning lib with dependencies.

Edit: I use Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: You could manually install them in your home folder and then link to them accordingly

Comment: This kind of problem may require distro-specific solution. What distribution and version are you using? Can you simply install another distribution that have what you need, either on bare metal or a virtual machine?